# jquery-ui autocomplete using ajax locks up keyboard input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jquery-ui's autocomplete to search for a string of interest, by sending data to a server, and fetching matches. The problem is that once I start typing, and the results start coming in (as shown in console.log), I'm unable to continue typing because input becomes locked (whatever I type no longer gets displayed). This is probably because of the volume of data. I could increase the minimum length at which autocomplete acts, but that defeats the purpose, which is to help a clinician search for a diagnosis, from almost 15,000 results, and get helpful hint.

My question is that, since on the server side, php seems to act quickly enough, how can I make javascript handle this data without locking up the keyboard input?

```js
$('body').on('focus', '#Diagnosis', function(){
  $(this).autocomplete({
    minLength: 5,
    autoFocus: true,
    source: function(request, response) {
        if (searchRequest !== null) {
            searchRequest.abort();
        }
        searchRequest = $.ajax({
            url: 'searchicd.php',
            method: 'post',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {term: request.term},
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                MyArray=data;
                searchRequest = null;
                response($.map(data.Disease, function(item, index) {
                    console.log(item);
                    return {
                                value: item,
                                label: item + "(" + data.Code[index] + ")"
                    };
                }));
            }
                }).
        fail(function() {
            searchRequest = null;
        });
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input" id="Diagnosis" aria-describedby="" placeholder="Diagnosis" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: check [JQuery UI Demo for Autocomplete which is remote with cache](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache), uses client cache.

Comment: I normally hold on from autocomplete until the user enters the first three characters. Also I limit the results to top 20-30 items, sorted by the name. Showing too many results on autocomplete is counter productive and annoying for the user.